# React - this.props en src

Tags: reactjs, src, props, this

Estoy aprendiendo a usar this.props en React pero cuando es un src me tira error.

```
<Card.Img variant="top" src={this.props.img}{this.props.img4}/>
    <Card.Body>
      <Card.Title>{this.props.titulo}{this.props.titulo4}</Card.Title>
      <Card.Text>
        {this.props.intro}{this.props.intro4}
      </Card.Text>
    </Card.Body>
    <Card.Footer>
```

En mi card me funciona perfecto usar dos props en las variables titulo e intro pero cuando quiero hacerlo con el src me dice "Line 10:50:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "..." "
Como lo harian?
Gracias !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola Ignacio basicamente la forma en como estas asignando el valor al src esta incorrecto, react usa las llaves para determinar que accederas a su contexto , en este caso tu estas creando {this.props.img}{this.props.img4} de la manera erronea recuerda que si deseas concatener string puedes usar el string interpolation y despues pasarle la concatenacion

```
const mySrc=`${this.props.titulo}${this.props.img4}`
```

Comment: Tu respuesta es la correcta, pero hace falta indicarle dónde tiene que ir esa string, que es en esta línea:
`<Card.Img variant="top" src={\`${this.props.img}${this.props.img4}\`}/>`